# How can I visit an IP address on Mobile Safari?

Tags: ios, network, mobile-safari

I am on iOS 7.0.4 on an iPhone 5. I type in a IP address on my local network, `192.168.11.18`, in my Safari address bar, and Safari completely ignores the fact that it is a host I am wanting to visit. Instead, it searches for `www.192.168.11.18` in my ISP's search engine.

How can I force Safari to visit the host I am requesting and not assume it's a search term?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem here and am wondering how you solved yours? Thanks! https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/284762/53510

Comment: I'm not sure what my issue was specifically, because it could've been quite a variety of issues. I think my issues probably stemmed from me not completely understanding how my particular local server was working. I'll hop over to your question and see if I can help.

Answer (score 5):

include `http://`

i.e.: `http://192.168.11.18`

(Tested this and it works perfectly)

Comment: Both `http://` and `http:\\ ` still didn't work.

Comment: sorry it should be `http://192.168.11.18` (my slashes were backwards) also you need to include the ip address after the `http://`

Comment: I ran into this too. `http://192.168.11.18` should definitely work. Double check the ip address though. If the server you are trying to reach doesn't respond (because it is at a different address or on a port other than 80) it will go back and try adding www to the front.

Comment: Okay, maybe the problem lies somewhere else in my network. The request must not have reached the server correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by connecting via another network. Probably it's a server issue. I tried

```
192.168.8.1
```

and

```
http://192.168.8.1
```

At first non of the url pattern worked for me but both seems to work now.